# OptionsMenu appears in double

Tags: android, options-menu

I Have a `Fragment` inside an `Activity`. This Activity contains `OptionsMenu`.

I use a `FragmentTransaction` to launch a new instance of the same Fragment class, when I selected the `OptionsMenu`, it appears in double because it load twice.

How can I do to manage OptionsMenu between the Fragments

Thanks.

PS : Sorry for the English

Comment: I find a part of the solution. I use FragmentTransaction and not an new Intent. But my new question is how to manage the OptionMenu inside the Fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution,

I create the OptionsMenu only in the Activity.
I get the OptionsItemsSelected on the Activity too.

When onOptionsItemSelected() occur, I get the current Fragment like this :

```
FragmentManager fg = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment frag = fg.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentMap);
```

All my Fragment have the same id but I always get the Fragment on the top. 
Then, I can call :

```
frag.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

to the Fragment receive and my UI is correctly update.

I hope It helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way such way. You can handle on BackPressed and show your own custom menu as a new fragmnet. Or manage your options menu inside of FragmentTransaction inactivity in dependent of your fragment  class and content

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with `setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)` in your `Fragment` extending classes, 
if that is set to true the `FragmentManager` should automatically call your current fragment's `onOptionsItemSelected`, 
it set to false you can manually call those callbacks yourself in your Activity's `onOptionsItemSelected`.

Worked for me... :)